# Delphi skinning libraries

Tags: delphi

I would like to know what is the best skinning library for Delphi application for you. I'm looking to WinXP/Windows Vista/Windows 7 compatibilities, so the application doesn't crash or work weird because of the skins. I have tried Theme Engine but it doen't work fine in Windows Vista.

I'm currently using Delphi 2006.

Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I used the [VCLSkin](http://www.link-rank.com/) component for an extended period with excellent results in Win xp, vista and 7. is extremely easy to use (you just drag the component to your main form to skin the entire application), fast, reliable and has lots of skins.

[image]
<sub>(source: [link-rank.com](http://www.link-rank.com/map/Longhorn%20Slate-Plex-SLATE.jpg))</sub>

[image]

Comment: +1 for VCL Skin.  I don't think I would have skinned my application if it were not for VCL Skin.  Very easy to use.  Many compliments on the resulting application.

Comment: +1 for VCL Skin.  I particularly like that this component can be applied to an existing application without having to replace existing components with "skinned" ones.

Answer (score 6):

DevExpress has a great skinning library. You can use their default skins or create your own. Supports all versions of Windows, AFAIK.
 Have a look at [their site](http://devexpress.com/Products/VCL/ExSkins/) for more information.

Comment: Thanks. DevExpress have some awesome components. I'm afraid they're the most expensive ones too ;)

Comment: If you're developping commercial applications, the DevExpress components are well worth the investement. We started buying one or two components and ended up with the complete VCL subscription. Small advantage for us was the euro/dollar exchange rate that made it affordable :-)

Comment: I use DevExpress skins as well. They are great and have a nice editor if you are bold enough to start making your own skin.

Answer (score 3):

I've been using [AlphaControls](http://www.alphaskins.com/) for a while, it's pretty slick and has worked well for me under everything from Win2000 to Win7.  It's still under active development, so if you hit a bug, they're there to try and fix it. :)

Answer (score 3):

I've just evaluted a number of skin components.

1. Suiskin.

   1. Very easy to install (Just run .exe)
   2. Very easy to use.
   3. Skins standard components well.
   4. Does skin whole app (Needs extra line of code for any non-auto-create forms).
   5. Good demo and good range of skins.
2. Alpha Controls

   1. Great library of appealing skins
   2. Brilliant demo program.
   3. Installation: Have to compile 2 packages and then install one of them. Do-able but not as profession as Suiskin.
   4. Skinning components work well. Skins the whole app  well. Skins standard controls and also have their own component set, which gives more options.
   5. Help is translated and is only average. Help on using the skin editor is difficult and a little incomplete.
   6. Can set hue offset and saturation. Hue offset is brilliant.. basically rotates all skinned colors on the colour wheel by the given amount. so.. blue ==> pink whilst yellow ==> green etc. Basically means that one skin suddenly comes in 4 to 6 decent color schemes.
   7. Skin editor came with bug.(I use XP) Couldn't set the directory to hold the skins. This was the first (& essential) step. Found that by putting the executable in the folder with the skins it could find them. After this, the editor seemed very efficient.
   8. Don't believe the web site that tells you that the basic licence is just for 1 year. It is a lifetime licence with just 1 year of included updates.

      Felt like Alpha skinning application was done by someone capable who gave it great power and efficiency, but didn't bother with the fine points(like help and looking professional and some minor bug fixes).
      I actually went with this component set.
3. KSDEV

   1. Professional install
   2. Skin editing program ran smoothly and professionally. Felt it was not as efficient in editing skins as alpha skins. This was one reason I didn't go with KSDEV.
   3. Professional website with good demo program.
   4. Good range of skins, but didn't feel as excited as alpha skins. This was the other reason I went alpha. I believe this component set also had a hue offset option. (It was this or suiskin, can't remember)
4. VCLSkin

   1. very few sample skins to view on website (that I could find).
   2. Couldn't find a demo program if there was one.
   3. downloaded vcl component set, but in the zip file it said it was netskin. At this point I gave up.

Answer (score 1):

I have worked with both [Theme Engine](http://ksdev.com/themeengine/index.html) and [Skin Engine](http://ksdev.com/skinengine/index.html) from [KSDev](http://www.ksdev.com/), with various success, although unlike you wrote it worked find in vista for me.

I personally found the skin editor to be a pestilence to work with, it was full of bugs, unstable at best, little to know documentation, but still more stable than the skin editor from Skincrafter.

As an alternative I know of a skin component called [Alpha Controls](http://www.alphaskins.com/), however I have not tried this myself, [Skin Crafter](http://www.skincrafter.com/products/skincrafter) whose editor I briefly mentioned above, also has a skinning library, my personal experience with this however is not the best.

I have not tried VCL skin which PRUZ mentioned myself so I cannot compare these engines to it, we looked at its specifications briefly when we were on the lookout for skin libraries for our application, but its lack of translucency was a too large burden for our designers * sigh *. Anyway I just wanted to give you some extra alternatives in case you needed some.

Comment: Thanks. I think I'll go for VCL Skins but I'll check the ones you said.

Answer (score 1):

There is also [TMS skin factory](http://www.tmssoftware.com/site/tsf.asp)