# Is it possible to buy/download/try components used in Adobe products like (Adobe Encore) for delphi?

Tags: delphi, delphi-7

Here is the screenshot of the Adobe Encore program.

Here you can see the set of the darkish components.

Can such be bought, downloaded, etc? Are they made public from Adobe Cor.?

Thanks

[image]

Comment: What about using a skin library like [AlphaControls](http://www.alphaskins.com/apack.php)?

Comment: Since the Adobe software is not written in Delphi, these controls are certainly not VCL controls.

Comment: If you are trying to replicate parts of Encore in a Delphi app, you might see if Adobe still provides a SDK that lets you utilize their products via OLE automation.  The SDK was available back in the days of Photoshop 7.  Don't know about now though.

Comment: I am only interested in components they used to build the app.

Comment: Use XE2 VCL styles. I must say though that apps that look like that make me barf.

Comment: I think most of this could be replicated using the TMS Component Pack. Just an idea.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan - I have often wondered what people think of skinned applications and if to use them or not. Maybe I should make this a question, although I don't think Stack Overflow would be appropriate place for such question?

Comment: @Shamballa: If you would ask such a question you would probably be heavily downvoted, and the question would be closed.

Comment: @AndreasRejbrand - Yes, I thought it would be. I will look for the correct route to post this before I do.

Comment: @David;  I find that it's not the look that makes me barf, it's the way the components glitch.  Yesterday I saw a weird problem with  CheckListBox where when I turn on VCL styles, with some border and other common VCL properties toggled to any setting you like, the controls glitch (paint incorrectly, mouse handling is off, when you click the wrong item toggles on and off, etc etc).  Gross!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The easiest way to achieve that look and feel is either:

1. To purchase a skin engine or component library that has skins enabled, if you must use an old version of Delphi prior to XE2.
2. But the preferred method is to just use the VCL skins library that comes in Delphi XE2, called VCL Styles. Unfortunately it has bugs, but so do all the other skin libraries.  You can also achieve similar results in Delphi XE2 using the Firemonkey framework, which like whatever non-delphi technology is used in Adobe products, eschews native controls for a completely self-contained environment that can look any way you want it to.

If you want funky/pretty user interfaces, personally, I recommend you get Delphi XE2.  If you insist on "try/buy/component" then I suggest you look into the Developer Express component suite, or one of the ones listed in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1969847/delphi-skinning-libraries) such as VCLSkin.